# Pandas: drop rows based on duplicated values in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to drop rows within my dataframe based on if a piece of a string is duplicated within that string.  For example, if the string is jkl-ghi-jkl, I would drop this row because jkl is repeated twice.  I figured that creating a list and checking the list for duplicates would be the ideal approach.

My dataframe for this example consist of 1 column and two data points:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['abc-def-ghi-jkl', 'jkl-ghi-jkl-mno'],})
```

My first step I take is to apply a split to my data, and split of "-"

```
    List = df1['Col1].str.split('-')
    List
```

Which is yields the output:

```
    0     [abc, def, ghi, jkl]
    1     [jkl, ghi, jkl, mno]
    Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

My second step I take is to convert my output into lists:

```
    List = List.tolist()
```

Which yields:

```
    [['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], ['jkl', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']]
```

My last step I wish to accomplish is to compare a full list with a distinct list of unique values:

```
    len(List) > len(set(List))
```

Which yields the error:

```
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am aware that my .tolist() creates a list of 2 series.  Is there a way to convert these series into a list in order to test for duplicates?  I wish to use this piece of code:

```
    len(List) > len(set(List)
```

with a drop in order to drop all rows with a duplicated value within each cell.

Is this the correct way of approaching, or is there a simpler way?

My end output should look like:

```
     Col1
     abc-def-ghi-jkl
```

Because string jkl-ghi-jkl-mno gets dropped due to "jkl" repeating twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another option, using `set` and `len`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['abc-def-ghi-jkl', 'jkl-ghi-jkl-mno'],})

df1['length'] = df1['Col1'].str.split('-').apply(set).apply(len)

print( df1 )

              Col1  length
0  abc-def-ghi-jkl       4
1  jkl-ghi-jkl-mno       3

df1 = df1.loc[ df1['length'] < 4 ]

print(df1)

              Col1  length
1  jkl-ghi-jkl-mno       3
```

Comment: I like this approach.  I actually modified it to fit my overall coding.  Instead of a lambda function, I had just made a conditional statement using `df1['Col1'].str.split('-').apply(set).apply(len) == df1['Col1'].str.split('-').apply(len)`.  Thanks for your input, appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `str.split` with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to get a Boolean indexer:

```
# Get a Boolean indexer for duplicates.
dupe_rows = df1['Col1'].str.split('-', expand=True)
dupe_rows = dupe_rows.apply(lambda row: row.duplicated().any(), axis=1)

# Remove the duplicates.
df1 = df1[~dupe_rows]
```

**Edit**

Another option is to use [`toolz.isdistinct`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.isdistinct) in a similar manner as the other answers:

```
import toolz

df1[df1.Col1.str.split('-').apply(toolz.isdistinct)]
```

Answer (score 3):

`split` `'Col1'` and apply a repeat checker using an efficient `numpy` algorithm.

```
def nerpt(lst):
    ti = np.triu_indices(len(lst), 1)
    a = np.array(lst)
    return (a[ti[0]] == a[ti[1]]).any()

df1[~df1.Col1.str.split('-').apply(nerpt)]
```

[image]

---

#### Timings

Pretty clear using `set` is most efficient.  This is reflective of @Luis's answer

Using `pd.concat([df1 for _ in range(10000)])`

```
rpt1 = lambda lst: not pd.Index(lst).is_unique
rpt2 = lambda lst: len(lst) != len(set(lst))
rpt3 = nerpt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I went the same route you did, but instead kept everything in one dataframe; used  `apply()` and indexed to get what I needed:

```
[in]:
gf1 = df1
gf1['Col2'] = gf1['Col1'].str.split('-')  #keep lists in same DF
gf1['Col3'] = gf1['Col2'].apply(set).apply(len) == gf1['Col2'].apply(len)
df1 = gf1['Col1'].loc[gf1['Col3'] == True]
df1
[Out]: 
0 abc-def-ghi-jkl
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```